# Change image opacity and add link background on mouseover on it

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

I have frame styles for the image:

```
.frame {
    background:#efefef;
    border:1px solid #f6f6f6;
    box-shadow: 0 0 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4); /* @todo Old Browsers Fix */
    margin-bottom:15px;
    padding:4px;
}
```

in one place of the project I work on, I have following HTML code:

```
<a href="#" class="preview">
    <img class="frame" src="http://placehold.it/288x159" alt="" />
</a>
```

Basically, I want to change file opacity on mouseover and add a background (preview icon) to the link. I have following code:

```
.preview img.frame {
    margin:0;
    position:relative;
}
.preview:hover {
    background:url('../img/icon_zoom.png') center center no-repeat;
    display:inline-block;
    z-index:40;
}
.preview img { /* @todo Add different browsers rules */
    opacity: 1;
    /*moz-transition-property:opacity;
    -moz-transition-timing-function:ease-out;
    -moz-transition-duration:500ms;*/
    -moz-transition:opacity 1s ease-in-out;
}
.preview:hover img {
    opacity:.5;
    -moz-transition:opacity 1s ease-in-out;
    /*-moz-transition-property:opacity;
    -moz-transition-duration:500ms;
    -moz-transition-timing-function:ease-out;*/
    display:block;
    position:relative;
    z-index:-1;
}
```

However I faced few issues:
- how can I show background only for image body (currently it's also being displayed on the border)?
- why opacity is not being changed in Chrome?

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/v2vtw/) added. As you may see, it works in FF, but not in Chrome.

Comment: May we have a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/), please?

Comment: The `-moz` prefix targets only Firefox. You need to find `-webkit` rules as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem appears to be that you're changing the `display` to `inline-block`. Take it out, it should have the same functionality and work just fine.

Changing a couple other things seems to have it working as you intended. http://jsfiddle.net/minitech/v2vtw/2/

Comment: Transition is working perfectly however, the preview icon appears under the image, it's not centered on the image for some reason. Any idea?

Comment: Adding `.preview { display:inline-block; }` did the job. Everything working perfectly.

Comment: @DaveW: Yeah, it's because it's not `display: inline-block` :) Okay, how about a rewrite? http://jsfiddle.net/minitech/v2vtw/4/ EDIT: Looks like you found the solution, never mind. :)